# Reversed Pub/Sub behavior in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the [jQuery Tiny Pub/Sub](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-tiny-pubsub) plugin for some loose coupling. The current behavior is the following:

- Publishing `foo` triggers `foo.bar`
- But publishing `foo.bar` doesn't triggers `foo`

The behavior I want is pretty much the reversed way:

- Publishing `foo.bar` triggers `foo`
- But publishing `foo` doesn't triggers `foo.bar`

Is there a plugin doing that or a way to get [jQuery Tiny Pub/Sub](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-tiny-pubsub) working this way?

Answer (score 0):

Tiny Pub/Sub is simply a rename of the jQuery `on`, `off`, `trigger` methods, tied to a single, central object (as you can easily infer by looking at its *really short* source).

I don't know any jQuery plugins for this, but don't think being a jQuery plugin should be a requirement at all. There are several pub/sub implementations  and message brokers available, bot for client-server publication and for client-side only loose-coupling.

One that may suite your purpose is [PubSubJS](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS).